# Jquery checkbox inside div checked one at time

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

So i have a div thats auto generated and inside are 3 check boxes with different id's & names and by default none of them are checked!! If one happens to get checked then i need the other two unchecked!!

So only one can be checked at a time ...

So all unchecked or only one checked!

```
<div class="configoptions">
    <table class="configtable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fieldlabel">Include:</td>
                <td class="fieldarea">
                    <label><input name="configoption[10]" id="co30" value="1" onclick="recalc()" type="checkbox">green</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="fieldlabel">Include:</td>
                <td class="fieldarea">
                    <label><input name="configoption[9]" id="co27" value="1" onclick="recalc()" type="checkbox">blue</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="fieldlabel">Include:</td>
                <td class="fieldarea">
                    <label><input name="configoption[11]" id="co31" value="1" onclick="recalc()" type="checkbox">white</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is what i used to uncheck all divs on page ready.. since initially i need them unchecked.. that works great... now i need to make it so only one is check at a time if it is checked! Can someone gimme a hand,? Thx in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: I think becouse he wants to uncheck. no?

Comment: You need radio buttons to do this.  If you do not preselect any radio buttons then they will all start unselected.

Comment: Thanks arun that works well!! I didnt realize radios came by default unselected..  Vytautas is right i needed uncheck too!! i think radios once "one" is selected no way of un selecting except refresh page. Thanks again Arun P !

Comment: EDIT: Arun that works great but can it only effect the checkboxes inside the div! I have a checkbox elsewhere on the page that need to be left out of this! So all check boxes inside a div with a class name of  "configoptions" to be part of the only one checked at a time rule..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `prop` function to change the checked property of checkbox and radio buttons

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pm73S/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it like so (using part of Arun P Johny's answer - I wanted to share for those of you who might come across this as well.)

```
(function($checkbox,options){                               
            $($checkbox).on('change', function() {                  
                $("input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop('checked', false);               
            });             
        });
```